# Expose a non-used attribute in a JSP file (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

We were recently taught about DTO's (Data-Transfer-Object) and why we should use them and not the object directly from the Database.

Our class is called `Product` with: `id, code, price, name, description`.
In View, we are only showing the `code, price, name and description`, so the `id` is unused.
Our trainer told us that we should use a DTO, were the `id` would be missing.Otherwise, she told us that she could expose the `id` in the view.

How could something like that be possible? We are using `.jsp` files, and those are compiled on the server-side, transformed in `.html` and sent to user. How could you possible expose a field not use?

Answer (score 0):

> Data Transfer Object that communicate with the database, In the
>   database you probably store only the properties like in your example,
>   id,code,price,name,description.

and the DTO is a simple POJO class having getter/setter methods

Than you can access the database from DTO's getter/setter and the property is most probably private.

> The id is uniquly identified the products in your table and no need to
>   show or expose from your presentation .jsp.

Comment: How this answers OP question? *[id] need to show or expose from your presentation* - this is arguable.